# C# Data received on UDP is always useless

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Here's my problem; I'm trying to make a UDP server - client interaction as a test. I want the client to send data to the server, and if the server matches data the server holds, it sends a reply. Simple, right? Here's some code:

Client send/receive code:

```
void TestUDP()
    {
        Socket sock_addr = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint srver_endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 36);
        string numbers = "1.2.3.4";
        byte[] srver_req = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TEST|" + numbers);

        sock_addr.SendTo(srver_req, srver_endpoint);

        EndPoint ref_endpoint = (EndPoint)srver_endpoint;
        byte[] req_reply = new byte[1000];
        sock_addr.ReceiveFrom(req_reply, ref ref_endpoint);

        string reply = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req_reply).Trim();

        string[] s_str = reply.Split('|');

        if (s_str[0] == "HEY")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("HEY");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO");
        }
    }
```

Now some server code:

```
public void start()
    {
        udp_sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        udp_sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);

        udp_thr = new Thread(udpListen);
        udp_thr.Start();
    }

    void udpListen()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 36);

        udp_sock.Bind(ip);

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)(sender);

        while (true)
        {
            udp_sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);

            Parse(data, Remote);
        }
    }

    void Parse(byte[] data, EndPoint Remote)
    {
        string decData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Trim();
        string[] s_str = decData.Split('|');
        byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[] { };

        switch (s_str[0])
        {
            case "TEST":
                string data1 = s_str[1];

                if (data1 == "1.2.3.4")
                {
                    sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HEY|");
                }
                else if(data1 != "1.2.3.4")
                {
                    sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("NO|");
                }

                udp_sock.SendTo(sendBuffer, Remote);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is, it ALWAYS says "NO", I have no idea why. To me this looks like it should work, what am I doing wrong??
I've put this socket onto Broadcast, because I'd also like to handle Broadcast requests with this too. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should add diagnostics to print out the *actual* data rather than just knowing that it's "right" or "wrong".

Next, the actual problem is that you're ignoring the result of `udp_sock.ReceiveFrom`. That will tell you how many bytes have actually been received. Currently, you're always converting *all 1024 bytes* into a string... which means you're likely to have trailing data which you *haven't* just received. Just using `Trim()` isn't a good way of countering that. `Trim()` doesn't count U+0000 as whitespace, and even if it *did* it still wouldn't be an appropriate approach - aside from anything else, you're reusing the same buffer later, so if you received a long message and then a shorter one, you'd end up with a mixture.

You want:

```
// TODO: Fix your variable names, which are inconsistent non-idiomatic
int bytesRead = udp_sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
Parse(data, bytesRead, Remote);
```

and change `Parse` to:

```
void Parse(byte[] data, int bytesRead, EndPoint remote)
{
    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
    ...
}
```

You need to do that on both the client and the server.

Also, given that the first branch of the `if`/`else` checks whether `data1` *is* "1.2.3.4", you don't need to then check that it *isn't*.

Comment: Thank you Jon for this well explained reply. I will make the changes right now. Thanks again!